# how to display a photo from database base on its id to another page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a huge problem and been having a hard time figuring it out.I want to pass down the image id i click on onto the 2nd page.The 2nd page then uses the id and echos out an image,image_text based on what i gave in the database.

1st page

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo "<div class='img-single'>
    <a href='images/fpage.php?image_id={$row['image_id']}'><img class='i' 
     src='images/".$row['image']."' ></a>
    <figcaption class='figcaption'>".$row['image_text']."</figcaption>


    </div>";

}
```

?>

2nd page

```
       <?php
        $image_id = $_GET['image_id'];


       ?>
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: There's no JavaScript in this code, nor does phpMyAdmin appear to be relevant. Please try and tag as narrowly as possible to get the right kind of attention on your question.

Answer (score 0):

So after passing the image id in a `a href='somepage.php&image_id=$image'` tag. On the 2nd page use:     
`if (isset($_GET['image_id'])) { $pic_id = $_GET['image_id']`
 Then make a select from database using pic_id
`mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT picture, name from table_name WHERE picture_id = '$pic_id' LIMIT 1;");` 
 echo the picture in image tags and your done.

 `<img src="<?php echo $picture; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>">`
`} // Close if(issset())` 
 I hope this helps.